# Возможно ли реализовать на javascript?

Tags: javascript

Идея такая допустим есть 10 билетов, каждый состоит из двух частей - из вопроса и пояснения предыдущего вопроса, т.е. прочитав вопрос я могу кликнуть на одну из трех ссылок (трех возможных варианта ответа) и в зависимости от правильности ответа, попасть на тот или иной билет с поздравлением с минипобедой  или пояснением и последующим вопросом. Проблема такая... можно ли силами js организовать все так, чтобы на экране выводился только один билет, при клике на одну из трех (двух) ссылок без перезагрузки страницы выводился другой билет, который соответствует нажатой ссылке. Можно ли это оформить при помощи ajax или мне будет необходим другой язык?
Спасибо

Comment: > Можно ли

Можно.

Comment: Тогда вопрос такой: Допустим тело билета выводится в диве, как можно сделать так, чтобы при клике на ссылку с вариантом ответа, силами js заменить тело текущего билета на новый...

Comment: То есть за вас вообще весь код написать, с нуля?

Comment: Нет нет, подскажите функцию, при помощи которой можно это осуществить

Comment: document.getElementById('elem').innerHTML = 'abc'

Comment: innerText ?

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я уже совсем имзмотался :-)

Comment: Почитай что-ли какой-нибудь учебник по веб-разработке, или самоучитель, или ещё что-то такое.